# C++ What can I use instead sleep() function?

Tags: c++, linux, timer

I'm building scrobbler, and I want my program to wait 10 seconds after song change, before scrobbling. I have been using sleep but I realized that if song change during these 10 seconds, program submit old song and get new one. I want If I change song, code start all over again.

I'm using Music Player Daemon (MPD) and libmpd to get songs' tags.

Note: program is under Unix.

Comment: How does your program recognize that a song has been changed? How do you intercept the event trigger? If you use a `read()`-able event (ie, with a file descriptor), you might be able to set a timeout with `select()`, which would mean that you can handle both ten-second pauses plus observe state changes.

Comment: Just as an aside, I'm pretty sure tracks are supposed to be scrobbled to last.fm once you've listened to half of the track.

Comment: @sftrabbit - No. This is my project. They are scrobbled to my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depens a lot on how your program works, but in principle, the easiest way would be to keep using sleep and **check** whether the user changed the song before sending out that data (after sleep has returned). So, instead of "try to sleep better", the goal would be "check that the data you send is really valid before sending".

A different possibility would be to wait on an `epoll` using either the timeout for sleeping or better yet on a `timerfd`, and notify song change via an `eventfd`. This has the advantage that it is "free" if you need reliable inter-thread communication and readiness notification anyway, which you most probably do (obviously you must have at least one additional GUI thread, or the user would not be able to change songs while you're blocking).

Comment: well the player is Music Player Daemon (MPD) Which is server. My program is connected to MPD and there is function called by MPD when song changes. That function call another function to extract datas and then 3rd function is called to send datas. Program is console (no GUI)

Comment: @CappY: No server can ever call functions in your program. Therefore there is a library in your program, that has an event-loop and calls your function when it gets data from the server. Since you have event-loop, you have to wait in a way compatible with that event-loop.

Comment: @CappY: Add this comment to the question, because the correct solution depends on this information. Mention all libraries you use, too.

Comment: So basically your program is a MPD client, and running in a single thread? Which means you listen to a socket for messages from the MPD server? Your code looks something like this right now? `while(!quit) { msg = recv(mpd_socket,...); parse(); usleep(10000); send(scrobble_socket,...); }`

Comment: @Damon: yeah. I'm using libmpd.

Comment: From what I can find about this library, it's deprecated, but anyway. There is a `mpd_playlist_get_current_song` function, which I assume you could just use after sleeping, what's the hindrance to doing so? This would make sure that the data you have is current, no?

Comment: @Damon : I think no.After sleeping, song is sent to website, and then new song is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Damon's suggestion is a good one and may be a better overall design. If you're looking for something quick though, you could consider simply sending a signal to your application when the song changes. That will interrupt the `sleep()` system call and cause it to return early. Your application would then just need to handle the early return as appropriate. Depending on your implementation, this may not be appropriate but it might give you a quick fix.